# How can i pad the edges of a rectangle with points?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm drawing a rectangle with the mouse and now i want that while i'm drawing the rectangle it will draw points on each of the rectangle edges bottom,top,keft,right.

This is how it look like when i'm drawing just the rectangle:

[image: Rectangle]

And i want that while i'm drawing the rectangle in real time to add/pad each edge of the rectangle with X number of points. For example on each edge 10 green points with exactly space between them.

For example i added the points in paint just to show what i mean:

[image: Rectangle Padded]

Just the green points should be in the thick of the red lines of the rectangle and on the red lines. 
The green points should be filled.
And there should be exact space between the points.

I just drawed some points on the top but it should be on the left bottom and right too.

This is how i draw now the regular rectangle just the rectangle.

In the top of form1:

```
private Bitmap _bmpBU = null;
public static Rectangle mRect;
```

In the constructor:

```
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
_bmpBU = new Bitmap(@"D:\MyWeatherStation-Images-And-Icons\radar090.PNG");
```

pictureBox1 mouse move event:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                mRect = new Rectangle(mRect.Left, mRect.Top, e.X - mRect.Left, e.Y - mRect.Top);
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            }
        }
```

pictureBox1 mouse down event:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mRect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
            Image iOLd = this.pictureBox1.Image;
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)_bmpBU.Clone();

            this.pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
            if (iOLd != null)
                iOLd.Dispose();
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
```

And the pictureBox1 paint event:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, mRect);
            }
        }
```

I need that somehow in the paint event while it's drawing the rectangle it will also pad and add the green points to each edge.

Comment: Your example is a little confusing because you said you wanted 10 points, but only drew 4. But are you saying, you'd like a function that you could pass in one of the 4 edges of the rectangle (North, South, East, West), and a number and it will draw that number of circles along one of the edges?

Comment: icemanind in my question i mentioned that the image i uploaded with the 4 points is just an example of what i want to do. It can be 4 points on each edge or 10 or 25 or 100 the user will decide. And for the second part you right i want to give a number let's say 12 and it will draw 12 filled points in same spaces between them on each edge North,South,East,West.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Point RectStartPoint;
private Image img;
private Image imgClone;
private Pen myPen;
private n = 10; //number of points
```

You have to initialize those objects, maybe in:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myPen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 2);
        //Bitmap to hold the picturebox image
        img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        Graphics g;
        using (g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
        {
            g.DrawImage(imageOfPicturebox, 0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        }

        //image to hold the original picturebox. We need it to clear img to the original 
        //picturebox image
        imgClone = (Bitmap)img.Clone();

        //We draw always on img and then we invalidate
        pictureBox1.Image = img;
    }

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        RectStartPoint = e.Location;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && e.Location != RectStartPoint)
        {
            DrawRectangle(e.Location);
        }
    }

    private void DrawRectangle(Point pnt)
    {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
        int width, height, i, x, y;

        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        //Clear img from the rectangle we drawn previously
        g.DrawImage(imgClone, 0, 0);


        if (pnt.X == RectStartPoint.X || pnt.Y == RectStartPoint.Y)
        {
            g.DrawLine(myPen, RectStartPoint.X, RectStartPoint.Y, pnt.X, pnt.Y);
        }
        else
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(myPen, Math.Min(RectStartPoint.X, pnt.X), Math.Min(RectStartPoint.Y, pnt.Y),
                            Math.Abs(RectStartPoint.X - pnt.X), Math.Abs(RectStartPoint.Y - pnt.Y));

            //width of spaces between points
            width = (int)((Math.Abs(RectStartPoint.X - pnt.X)) / (n - 1));
            //height of spaces between points
            height = (int)((Math.Abs(RectStartPoint.Y - pnt.Y)) / (n - 1));
            //we always want the upper left x, y coordinates as a reference drawing clockwise
            x = Math.Min(RectStartPoint.X, pnt.X);
            y = Math.Min(RectStartPoint.Y, pnt.Y);

            //Drawing the points. change the 3, 6 values for larger ones
             for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                //Up side
                g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, new Rectangle(x - 3, Math.Min(RectStartPoint.Y, pnt.Y) - 3, 6, 6));
                //Right side
                g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, new Rectangle(Math.Min(RectStartPoint.X, pnt.X) + Math.Abs(RectStartPoint.X - pnt.X) - 3, y - 3, 6, 6));
                //Bottom side
                g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, new Rectangle(x - 3, Math.Min(RectStartPoint.Y, pnt.Y) + Math.Abs(RectStartPoint.Y - pnt.Y) - 3, 6, 6));
                //Left side
                g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, new Rectangle(Math.Min(RectStartPoint.X, pnt.X) - 3, y - 3, 6, 6));

                x += width;
                y += height;
            }
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, new Rectangle(Math.Min(RectStartPoint.X, pnt.X) + Math.Abs(RectStartPoint.X - pnt.X) - 3, 
                          Math.Min(RectStartPoint.Y, pnt.Y) - 3, 6, 6));
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, new Rectangle(Math.Min(RectStartPoint.X, pnt.X) + Math.Abs(RectStartPoint.X - pnt.X) - 3,
                         Math.Min(RectStartPoint.Y, pnt.Y) + Math.Abs(RectStartPoint.Y - pnt.Y) - 3, 6, 6));
        }

        g.Dispose();

        //draw img to picturebox
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't this draw __on the PictureBox__ as the OP does. It draws __into the Image__, messing it up. If it's OK with the OP, then fine.. And I don't see the Paint event.

Comment: @TaW *imgClone* has the original image. Before painting on *img* we clear it with *imgClone* (see line *g.DrawImage(imgClone, 0, 0);* in *DrawRectangle()* sub). So we dont *messing it up*. I never draw in paint event. It is not a matter of preference but a better way to handle your drawings. Lets say you have 10 buttons and each draws a different shape. You need to use an *if else if* statement in paint to check which button draws. With my method i am clearing *img* with *imgClone*, draw on *img* and *invalidate*. That simple

Comment: so it should be corrected and amended with the points, but that's just my view. Your explanations make no sense to me, but, maybe that's just me. For 10-100 shapes I would always prefer to draw them over manipulating a bitmap, but to each his own..

Comment: @TaW *...it should be corrected and amended with the points*. It is corrected and amended with points. The *if-else* statement draws the rectangle, and the *for-loop* draws the points! *For 10-100 shapes I would always prefer to draw them over manipulating a bitmap,...* what is different with my approach. I am also drawing to a bitmap *img* and invalidate. I was anwsering to your statement *And I don't see the Paint event*, and explained clearly that i do not draw in paint.

Answer (score 1):

This is just math. Add this function:

```
private void DrawPointsOnRectangle(Graphics g, int numberOfPoints)
{
    var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkGreen);
    const int rectanglePenWidth = 2;

    //North & South
    int spacing = mRect.Width / (numberOfPoints - 1);

    for (int x = 0; x < numberOfPoints; x++)
    {
        g.FillEllipse(brush, mRect.X + (x * spacing) - rectanglePenWidth - 5, mRect.Y - 7, 15, 15);
        g.FillEllipse(brush, mRect.X + (x * spacing) - rectanglePenWidth - 5, mRect.Y - 7 + mRect.Height, 15, 15);    
    }

    //East & West
    spacing = mRect.Height/(numberOfPoints - 1);

    for (int y = 0; y < numberOfPoints; y++)
    {
        g.FillEllipse(brush, mRect.X - rectanglePenWidth - 5, mRect.Y - 7 + (y * spacing), 15, 15);
        g.FillEllipse(brush, mRect.X - rectanglePenWidth - 5 + mRect.Width, mRect.Y - 7 + (y * spacing), 15, 15);
    }
}
```

And modify your `pictureBox1_Paint` function to call the new function:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, mRect);
        DrawPointsOnRectangle(e.Graphics, 5);
    }
}
```

That should do it! You can change the `5` parameter to however many points you want on each side.

Comment: icemanind this is working great. Justo ne question could you describe or tell me what the numbers 7 and 15 do ? And how can i change the points size to be smaller or bigger ?

Comment: For example if i want that the green points to be on the same size of the rectangle red line. The red line thick is 2.0f but the green points are bigger then that.